# Use datatable single cell selection to subset a dataframe in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny app below in which I want to be able to click on a certain column-single-and create a 2nd datatable with only this cell. The issue is that I cannot achieve this as I do it with row selection which gives back the row index which I use to subset. In this case I use a 1st row -3rd column example.

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(

  title = 'Select Table Rows',


  h1('A Server-side Table'),

  fluidRow(
    column(9, DT::dataTableOutput('x3')),
    column(3, DT::dataTableOutput('x4'))
  )

)
#server.r
   library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # server-side processing
  mtcars2 = mtcars[, 1:8]
  output$x3 = DT::renderDataTable(mtcars2, server = TRUE,selection=list(target='cell'))

  # print the selected indices
  output$x4 = DT::renderDataTable({
    if(as.character(input$x3_cells_selected)=="1, 3"){
      mtcars[1,3]
    }

  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need -

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Select Table Rows',
  h1('A Server-side Table'),
  fluidRow(
    column(9, DT::dataTableOutput('x3')),
    column(3, DT::dataTableOutput('x4'))
  )
)
#server.r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # server-side processing
  mtcars2 = mtcars[, 1:8]
  output$x3 = DT::renderDataTable(mtcars2, server = TRUE,
                                  selection=list(target='cell'))

  # print the selected indices
  output$x4 = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$x3_cells_selected)
    mtcars[input$x3_cells_selected[,1], input$x3_cells_selected[,2], drop = F]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.First I added the mode='single' in the selection list in order to select only one cell at a time. Secondly I used the 'if' argument in my initial Q because I want this logic to be implemented only when I click on cerain cells of mtcars (or certain columns at least). Can this be achieved?

Comment: I think that works with if(input$x3_cells_selected[,1]==1&input$x3_cells_selected[,2]==3)